# Show all records in one cell

Tags: reporting-services, expression, business-intelligence

I got this Dataset:

```
Select TBL_NEWS.TITLE, COUNT(*) as TITLE_COUNT
from TBL_NEWS
GROUP BY TBL_NEWS.TITLE
ORDER BY TBL_NEWS.TITLE
```

And I am using this as expression:

```
=Count(Fields!TITLE.Value)
```

And it shows 1 in 365 rows, what I want is `365` only on one row. In a nutshell, I want the number of records of that `dataset`, how can I do this?

Comment: Simply `Select COUNT(*) as TITLE_COUNT from TBL_NEWS`?

Comment: I used that and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Great! You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Table` component to display content of your dataset you need to place `COUNT(Fields!TITLE.Value)` to `Table Footer`.